# Conceptual query: Is the file in use transferred to the local machine in SSH?

Tags: ssh

I work on a remote machine terminal through ssh (from the local machine) to run a program which uses, as input, a file of size nearly 1GB.

My question is, when this program is run over ssh, is the file transferred to my local machine in any way? Or is it directly taken from the remote machine and the local machine is not at all involved other that showing the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ssh, you run a command remotely, on the target system.

It doesn't transfer anything unless you ask it to - but it does (by default) return you the output of that command.

So if you `ssh user@somehost grep someword somefile` then it'll process the file on `somehost` and just give you the matches. That *might* end up being the whole file, but it probably won't be.

Comment: Is this the same when I download a file over a remote browser (opened using x forwarding in the local machine)...to a location in the remote only. Cause I always see a lesser speed of download. I figured, the local machine must be involved which is slowing the speed down.

Comment: The data from X windows must pass over the ssh tunnel - and be encrypted. That's potentially more data (graphics) than the HTML content would be.

Answer (score 1):

When you run commands through `ssh` they run on the server. Only the terminal output and input is transferred over the wire.

A `wc 10GBTextFile` will most certainly not download the file and count words on the client machine.

A `cat 10GBTextFile` will try to send the contents to the terminal (and over the network), though.